# My Elementor pro is not working on my genesis theme

Tags: wordpress, elementor

My Element-or pro is not working on my genesis theme. Before i am using the element-or but element-or pro is not working on my genesis theme. Can anyone know the solution. Thanks

http://i.prntscr.com/v5qkHcGeSvabjNTZ0FHSyg.png
http://i.prntscr.com/7dHVmqLOT9yRXHbLoupwjA.png

Answer (score 0):

basically these warning show that your elementor pro is not compatible with your elementor page builder.

**Now you have two choices:**

- Update your elementor pro to latest version
- Or downgrade your elementor page builder version one by one so see which is the highest compatible version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have the elementor pro plugin